# Unity3D Choppy Camera Motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, jitter

I tried many different methods but never succeed to make a perfectly smooth camera movement.
Even in a very simple scene, camera follow is not good enough. There are spikes in motion. Spikes do not occur periodically but randomly. If I didn't know some games(e.g. Manuganu) made in unity and has a perfect camera follow, I would think it is impossible.

What I have tried so far:
-Change camera position in LateUpdate/FixedUpdate.
-Made my target interpolate/extrapolate.
-Moved camera depending on Deltatime.
-Increased physics steps.
-Set the targetframerate = 60.
-Played with all Quality settings, Vsync etc.
-Many variations and other things...

The best scenario is, random hiccups...happening in both mobile and editor.
Unity's example scripts doesn't work perfectly smooth either.
I can't continue developing sidescroll runner game because of this hiccup problem.

The question is: is there any way I didn't mention, is there any example on the Internet?
I did everything I can do.

```
transform.position = new Vector3(target.x, target.y, -10);
```

This is how I update camera position in LateUpdate.

PS: There is no FPS drop issue.

Comment: Your question being? There's a countless number of potential issues here, you ought to at least post the code that moves the camera.

Comment: Actually there is no countless potential issues because the thing I am trying to do is ridicilously simple. As you said, I added the code.Thanks

Comment: how does target change its position respectivel how do you calculate it?

Comment: Target has a velocity by Physics, there is no problem with my target but all other objects.

Comment: I tried my project on a macbook, there is no hiccup at all. Weird.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1):

@Kashbel has half of it. You're using a fixed movement value but there is no guarantee that every frame takes the same amount of real world time. You need to make sure that the units-per-second is constant, which means you need to use the time to control the speed of the update.

The typical way to handle this is to use `Time.DeltaTime`, which will always be a tiny fraction representing the real world length of the frame in seconds.  For example, as in the docs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        float translation = Time.deltaTime * 10;
        transform.Translate(0, 0, translation);
    }
}
```

here the script will move it's gameObject 10 units *per second*, regardless of framerate. Without the `Time.deltaTime` it might move 10 units in 1/60th of a second on one frame but 10 units in 1/15th of a second on a particularly slow frame.

Comment: I have tried lerp before and didn't make any change. Thanks for answer, how can I use this code to follow an object?

Comment: My target has a rigid body and velocity. Tried your code and still see random hicups.

Comment: You probably need a framerate counter so you can distinguish between hiccups in the update code and big spikes in the running of the game overall.  Occasional long pauses often mean you're creating lots  of objects and then getting garbage collection pauses.

Comment: My scene is so simple, creating no new objects, hiccups are very short but disturbing. There are sprites, a character and a camera. i can send the project.

Comment: You should look at it under the profiler and see if there any clues. Maybe network code? Or is you computer itelf having hiccups?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBpXiJ9G3OY

Comment: It happens on laptop and mobile devices. Anyway thanks! for your time, I will post the question on unity answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Lerp` function instead directly moving the `transform.position`.

It would be something like `transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, time);`

It should be smooth using this. You have more information and examples at [Vector3.Lerp Unity3D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: I tried many types of it, result: random hiccups. There is no problem with target but all other objects.